While running a piece of driver code on an AMD64 machine, it appears that there are issues related to cache consistency or out-of-order execution
While running a piece of driver code on an AMD64 machine, it appears that there are issues related to cache consistency or out-of-order execution. Are there any experienced engineers who can help analyze the cause?
Below is the C code for the corresponding function and the disassembled code of the compiled program.
static int check_status(struct cmd_dst *out)
{
        uint32_t loops = 0;

        printf("before loop, status is 0x%x\n", out->status);

        while (*(volatile uint32_t *)&out->status) {
                _mm_pause();
                loops++;
        }

        if (out->status) {
                printf("status error with 0x%x\n", out->status);
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}

int check_cmd{}
{
...
        if (out->status && check_status(out)) {
                printf("failed to execute cmd, status error 0x%x\n", out->status);
        }
...
}



0x000000000002c1b9 <+297>:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x000000000002c1c0 <+304>:   mov    0x0(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000002c1c3 <+307>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x000000000002c1c5 <+309>:   je     0x2c240 <check_cmd+432>
   0x000000000002c1c7 <+311>:   nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x000000000002c1d0 <+320>:   pause
   0x000000000002c1d2 <+322>:   mov    0x0(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000002c1d5 <+325>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x000000000002c1d7 <+327>:   jne    0x2c1d0 <check_cmd+320>
   0x000000000002c1d9 <+329>:   mov    0x0(%rbp),%r9d
   0x000000000002c1dd <+333>:   test   %r9d,%r9d
   0x000000000002c1e0 <+336>:   jne    0x2c240 <check_cmd+432>
   0x000000000002c1e2 <+338>:   mov    0x1c(%rbx),%esi
   0x000000000002c1e5 <+341>:   xor    %r12d,%r12d
   0x000000000002c1e8 <+344>:   test   %esi,%esi
   0x000000000002c1ea <+346>:   js     0x2c111 check_cmd+129>
   0x000000000002c1f0 <+352>:   jmpq   0x2c120 <check_cmd+144>
   0x000000000002c1f5 <+357>:   nopl   (%rax)
   0x000000000002c1f8 <+360>:   mov    0x25cde1(%rip),%rax        # 0x288fe0
   0x000000000002c1ff <+367>:   mov    $0x3b6,%r8d
   0x000000000002c205 <+373>:   lea    0x50094(%rip),%rcx        # 0x7c2a0
   0x000000000002c20c <+380>:   lea    0x4f975(%rip),%rdx        # 0x7bb88
   0x000000000002c213 <+387>:   mov    $0x1,%esi
   0x000000000002c218 <+392>:   mov    $0xffffffea,%r12d
   0x000000000002c21e <+398>:   mov    (%rax),%rdi
   0x000000000002c221 <+401>:   xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000002c223 <+403>:   callq  0x5250 <__fprintf_chk@plt>
   0x000000000002c228 <+408>:   add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x000000000002c22c <+412>:   mov    %r12d,%eax

out->status points to a piece of DMA memory, initially containing a random number (this random number is actually the input data for the hardware each time the command is executed, and the input data is random each time. The hardware's output is also written to this address). At some point, the hardware will write a 0 to out->status (indicating that the command has successfully executed). This write will only happen once and will not change afterward.
The program can be considered single-threaded, with no other thread operating on this memory region.
Under expected conditions, as long as the memory is non-zero, it will remain within the loop. Once the loop ends, this memory should be 0, therefore the function should only return 0.
However, during actual execution, it is observed that the function occasionally returns 1. At this point, printing status shows that it is the same as the value printed before the loop. After returning 1, logging out->status outside the function shows that it has become 0 again. What could be the possible reason for this?
The program's log is as follows:
before loop, status is 0x83ae
status error with 0x83ae
failed to execute cmd, status error 0x0

Adding the volatile keyword to the access of out->status in the check after the loop makes the problem disappear:
if (*(volatile uint32_t *)&out->status) {
    printf("status error with 0x%x\n", out->status);
    return 1;
}

Alternatively, inserting a memory barrier before the check also resolves the issue:
__sync_synchronize();
if (out->status) {
    printf("status error with 0x%x\n", out->status);
    return 1;
}

I think the only plausible explanation for this phenomenon is out-of-order execution. From the disassembled instructions, the subsequent check also reads directly from the memory address, and its order is after the read within the while loop. Therefore, if the while loop reads a 0 and the if statement reads a non-zero value, it appears as though the read instruction in the if statement is executed before the read instruction in the while loop, leading to this result.
However, upon reviewing the AMD64 manual, I have not found any sections that support this explanation. The manual's discussion on out-of-order execution pertains to rules when there is a dependency between reads and writes, and it does not seem to describe whether two read instructions from the same memory location could be executed out of order.

Compiled with gcc -O3 -g, the interleaved source code and assembly code generated by objdump -dS are as follows (note that some of the log entries used for debugging differ slightly from the original text, please disregard the content printed by printf):
int check_cmd(int algo_ctx_idx)
{
    2170:       41 57                   push   %r15
    2172:       41 56                   push   %r14
    2174:       41 55                   push   %r13
    2176:       41 54                   push   %r12
    2178:       55                      push   %rbp
    2179:       53                      push   %rbx
    217a:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
        struct algo_ctx *ctx = get_algo_ctx_by_idx(algo_ctx_idx);
    217e:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2183 <check_cmd+0x13>
        struct hw_queue *hq = NULL;
        struct algo_dst *out = NULL;
        int ret = 0;
...

        hq = get_hq_by_idx(ctx->hq_idx);
    21c6:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  21cb <check_cmd+0x5b>
    21cb:       49 89 c6                mov    %rax,%r14
        if (unlikely(!hq)) {
    21ce:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
    21d1:       74 22                   je     21f5 <check_cmd+0x85>
                goto __end;
        }

        out = hq->dma_mem + ctx->mem_off;
    21d3:       48 63 6b 1c             movslq 0x1c(%rbx),%rbp
                ret = -EIO;
                goto __release;
        } else {
                ret = 0;
    21d7:       45 31 e4                xor    %r12d,%r12d
        out = hq->dma_mem + ctx->mem_off;
    21da:       48 89 ee                mov    %rbp,%rsi
    21dd:       48 03 a8 90 00 00 00    add    0x90(%rax),%rbp
        if (out->status && check_status(out)) {
    21e4:       44 8b 6d 00             mov    0x0(%rbp),%r13d
    21e8:       45 85 ed                test   %r13d,%r13d
    21eb:       0f 85 af 00 00 00       jne    22a0 <check_cmd+0x130>
        }
__release:
        if (ctx->mem_off >= 0 && hq_mem_free(hq->idx_in_pool, ctx->mem_off)) {
    21f1:       85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
    21f3:       79 1b                   jns    2210 <check_cmd+0xa0>
                ret = -EINVAL;
        }
__end:
        return ret;
}
    21f5:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    21f9:       44 89 e0                mov    %r12d,%eax
    21fc:       5b                      pop    %rbx
    21fd:       5d                      pop    %rbp
    21fe:       41 5c                   pop    %r12
    2200:       41 5d                   pop    %r13
    2202:       41 5e                   pop    %r14
    2204:       41 5f                   pop    %r15
    2206:       c3                      retq
    2207:       66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    220e:       00 00
        if (ctx->mem_off >= 0 && hq_mem_free(hq->idx_in_pool, ctx->mem_off)) {
    2210:       41 8b be b8 00 00 00    mov    0xb8(%r14),%edi
    2217:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  221c <check_cmd+0xac>
    221c:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
    221e:       74 d5                   je     21f5 <check_cmd+0x85>
    2220:       48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # 2227 <check_cmd+0xb7>
    2227:       44 8b 4b 1c             mov    0x1c(%rbx),%r9d
    222b:       41 b8 db 03 00 00       mov    $0x3db,%r8d
    2231:       48 8d 0d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rcx        # 2238 <check_cmd+0xc8>
    2238:       48 8d 15 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdx        # 223f <check_cmd+0xcf>
    223f:       be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
                ret = -EINVAL;
    2244:       41 bc ea ff ff ff       mov    $0xffffffea,%r12d
    224a:       48 8b 38                mov    (%rax),%rdi
    224d:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    224f:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2254 <check_cmd+0xe4>
    2254:       eb 9f                   jmp    21f5 <check_cmd+0x85>
    2256:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    225d:       00 00 00
    2260:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    2264:       41 b8 c3 03 00 00       mov    $0x3c3,%r8d
    226a:       be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
                ret = -EINVAL;
    226f:       41 bc ea ff ff ff       mov    $0xffffffea,%r12d
    2275:       51                      push   %rcx
    2276:       48 8d 0d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rcx        # 227d <check_cmd+0x10d>
    227d:       52                      push   %rdx
    227e:       48 8d 15 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdx        # 2285 <check_cmd+0x115>
    2285:       50                      push   %rax
    2286:       48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # 228d <check_cmd+0x11d>
    228d:       48 8b 38                mov    (%rax),%rdi
    2290:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax

    2292:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2297 <check_cmd+0x127>
                goto __end;
    2297:       48 83 c4 20             add    $0x20,%rsp
    229b:       e9 55 ff ff ff          jmpq   21f5 <check_cmd+0x85>
        while (*(volatile uint32_t *)&out->status) {
    22a0:       8b 45 00                mov    0x0(%rbp),%eax
    22a3:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
    22a5:       74 69                   je     2310 <check_cmd+0x1a0>
    22a7:       66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    22ae:       00 00
    22b0:       f3 90                   pause
    22b2:       8b 45 00                mov    0x0(%rbp),%eax
    22b5:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
    22b7:       75 f7                   jne    22b0 <check_cmd+0x140>
        if (out->status) {
    22b9:       44 8b 6d 00             mov    0x0(%rbp),%r13d
    22bd:       45 85 ed                test   %r13d,%r13d
    22c0:       75 4e                   jne    2310 <check_cmd+0x1a0>
    22c2:       8b 73 1c                mov    0x1c(%rbx),%esi
                ret = 0;
    22c5:       45 31 e4                xor    %r12d,%r12d
        if (ctx->mem_off >= 0 && hq_mem_free(hq->idx_in_pool, ctx->mem_off)) {
    22c8:       85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
    22ca:       0f 88 25 ff ff ff       js     21f5 <check_cmd+0x85>
    22d0:       e9 3b ff ff ff          jmpq   2210 <check_cmd+0xa0>
    22d5:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
    22d8:       48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # 22df <check_cmd+0x16f>
    22df:       41 b8 bb 03 00 00       mov    $0x3bb,%r8d
    22e5:       48 8d 0d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rcx        # 22ec <check_cmd+0x17c>
    22ec:       48 8d 15 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdx        # 22f3 <check_cmd+0x183>
    22f3:       be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
                ret = -EINVAL;
    22f8:       41 bc ea ff ff ff       mov    $0xffffffea,%r12d
    22fe:       48 8b 38                mov    (%rax),%rdi
    2301:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    2303:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2308 <check_cmd+0x198>
                goto __end;
    2308:       e9 e8 fe ff ff          jmpq   21f5 <check_cmd+0x85>
    230d:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
    2310:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2315 <check_cmd+0x1a5>
    2315:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    2319:       4c 8b 25 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%r12        # 2320 <check_cmd+0x1b0>
    2320:       41 b8 ca 00 00 00       mov    $0xca,%r8d
    2326:       41 55                   push   %r13
    2328:       49 89 c1                mov    %rax,%r9
    232b:       49 89 c7                mov    %rax,%r15
    232e:       48 8d 0d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rcx        # 2335 <check_cmd+0x1c5>
    2335:       49 8b 3c 24             mov    (%r12),%rdi
    2339:       48 8d 15 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdx        # 2340 <check_cmd+0x1d0>
    2340:       be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
    2345:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    2347:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  234c <check_cmd+0x1dc>
    234c:       8b 43 1c                mov    0x1c(%rbx),%eax
    234f:       49 8b 3c 24             mov    (%r12),%rdi
    2353:       4d 89 f9                mov    %r15,%r9
    2356:       be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
    235b:       41 b8 d1 03 00 00       mov    $0x3d1,%r8d
    2361:       48 8d 0d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rcx        # 2368 <check_cmd+0x1f8>
                ret = -EIO;
    2368:       41 bc fb ff ff ff       mov    $0xfffffffb,%r12d
    236e:       50                      push   %rax
    236f:       8b 43 08                mov    0x8(%rbx),%eax
    2372:       48 8d 15 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdx        # 2379 <check_cmd+0x209>
    2379:       50                      push   %rax
    237a:       8b 45 00                mov    0x0(%rbp),%eax
    237d:       50                      push   %rax
    237e:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    2380:       53                      push   %rbx
    2381:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2386 <check_cmd+0x216>
                goto __release;
    2386:       8b 73 1c                mov    0x1c(%rbx),%esi
    2389:       48 83 c4 30             add    $0x30,%rsp
    238d:       e9 5f fe ff ff          jmpq   21f1 <check_cmd+0x81>
    2392:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
    2396:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    239d:       00 00 00

        return ret;
}


My guess is that check_command() is incorrectly using a (register?) cached copy of out->status from when the command was issued rather than fetching the value it points to. That doesn't explain why it only happens when the command value is 1 though.

@MartinBrown check_status eventually returns 1, but after check_cmd gets the check_status return, the status changes to 0 in the printed log

I think the mov    0x0(%rbp),%eax at check_cmd <+304> is from the first half of if (out->status && check_status(out)) {, before an inlined version of the function.  So that initial check isn't getting optimized away, @MartinBrown.  But it's hard to tell (or a lot of work to tell) since the OP didn't show interleaved source & asm (objdump -dS on a build that used gcc -O3 -g), or a [mcve] with a https://godbolt.org/ link where we could look at it.

@PeterCordes Hello, the interleaved source code and assembly code generated by objdump that you mentioned has been uploaded to the end. The line <check_cmd+304> in the first uploaded disassembly code corresponds to line <22a0> in the newly uploaded code. It appears that line <21e4> is the one corresponding to the first half of "if (out->status && check_status(out))".

I don't think there's any machine that would reorder loads and stores of the same address. That would be an impossibly weak memory model. 99% likely this is a compiler optimization, as evidenced by the fact that volatile fixes it.

It really would help to see a self-contained example on godbolt.
